# How to set className for selected child component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to ReactJs - I have had a look at the documentation [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html) and [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) but I am a bit confused.

So I have a component that creates several table rows according to the JSON data.

I am trying to make it so once a radio button is selected, the class of the parent `<td>` is set to 'success'. But at the moment all the rows with that column get the same class name.

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            site: '',
            address: '',
            data: [],
            checked: ''
        };
    },
    onSiteChanged: function (e) {
        this.setState({
            site: e.currentTarget.value,
            checked: 'success'
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var resultRows = this.props.data.map(function (result) {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td className={this.state.checked}>
                        <input type="radio" name="site_name"
                            value={result.SITE_NAME}
                            onChange={this.onSiteChanged}
                            key={result.id}/>{result.SITE_NAME}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="address"
                            value={result.ADDRESS}
                            onChange={this.onAddressChanged} />{result.ADDRESS}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        }, this);
        return (
            <table className="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {resultRows}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{this.state.site}</td>
                        <td>{this.state.address}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

What is the best ReactJS way to proceed to make sure the selected result get the selected class name?
Thank you.

Comment: I think there's an error in the code, shouldn't key={resultRows.id} be key={result.id}?

Comment: @ColinRamsay good catch, fixed in the question.

Comment: Also just to clarify, are you trying to set the className on the parent TD or the parent TR?

Comment: trying to change it on the selected <td>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify values passed to classSet property React has special addon: [React.addons.classSet](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html). It is very handy when you are changing multiple different classes but in your case it can be usefull, too:

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            site: '',
            address: '',
            checked: false,
            data: [],
        };
    },
    onSiteChanged: function (selected) {
        this.setState({
            site: selected.SITE_NAME,
            checked: selected.id,
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var resultRows = this.props.data.map(function (result) {
            var cx = React.addons.classSet({
                success: (this.state.checked === result.id)
            });
            return (
                <tr key={result.id}>
                    <td className={cx}>
                        <input type="radio" name="site_name"
                            value={result.SITE_NAME}
                            onChange={this.onSiteChanged.bind(this, result)}
                            />{result.SITE_NAME}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="address"
                            value={result.ADDRESS}
                            onChange={this.onAddressChanged} />{result.ADDRESS}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        }, this);
        return (
            <table className="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {resultRows}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{this.state.site}</td>
                        <td>{this.state.address}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: What if two radio buttons happen to have the same value? in that case `success: (this.state.site === result.SITE_NAME)` will set success for both of them. Whereby only the selected radio button shall get the success class.  Its a bit tricky.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. In this case we can keep track which one is selected by storing result.id in state. Let me update my response. I'm assuming that your id are unique between all radio buttons.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this working, it does not seem to add the className. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Kash I forgot to update code for onSiteChanged to make it work. My answer is updated now so take a look at it.

Comment: @daniula interesting solution. It works. But are there any concerns regarding using binding within React? `onChange={this.onSiteChanged.bind(this, result)}` It won't slow down if there are too many bindings will it? Thanks

Comment: @Houman React is doing binding on default, so there shouldn't be any overhead. I'm just changing what arguments are passed to event handler. Also see that I moved key property from <input> to <tr> because React needs that when you are creating array of elements.

Comment: @daniula Thanks for clarifying bindings. I am quite a beginner myself. I removed the `key={result.id}` and it still works. Why are keys needed in first place?

Comment: If you remove key property React will output warning message in browser console. There could be some weird issues when you will start updating content inside one of elements. For more see [Dynamic Children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) section in React docs.